# Flask server not starting for SocketIO

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, socket.io

I am trying to make a chat app using SocketIO and following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdSrkkrj3l4 and the corresponding GitHub code: https://github.com/PrettyPrinted/flask-socketio-chat

This file is my `main.py` file

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on('message')
def handleMessage(msg):
    print("Message:" + msg)
    send(msg, broadcast=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

and this is my index.html page

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chat Room</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.8/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000');

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        socket.send('User has connected!');
    });

    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        $("#messages").append('<li>'+msg+'</li>');
        console.log('Received message');
    });

    $('#sendbutton').on('click', function() {
        socket.send($('#myMessage').val());
        $('#myMessage').val('');
    });

});
</script>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<input type="text" id="myMessage">
<button id="sendbutton">Send</button>
</body>
</html>
```

However when I run the flask code using python main.py. It never loads anything and just shows this:

[Output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0hg16.png)

```
C:\Users\Harshit Parikh\Desktop\app>python main.py
```

Please help me out.

Comment: humm, seems your code is fine, try to check your network permissions, or try to start the server with ```app.run()``` insted ```socketio.run(app)``` to see the problem is with flask or only with socketIO

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar problem. I came across this question. I unistalled greenlet and the code worked fine. I don't know why that happend. But code worked fine now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I used `app.run()` instead of `socketio.run(app)`, like Caio suggested in the comment below the question. That worked for me.

After it started, I switched back to `socketio.run` and my application still works. Perhaps socketio needed some kind of kickstart?

Answer (score -1):

It worked when using a virtual environment and installing all the libraries again.